# How to set the data in datatable

Tags: asp.net

I executing the query I get the result as below format

```
ID  Name      Date          MF  SOB PCB
1001    KIRAN   02/08/2015  10  20  10
1002    KIRAN   03/O8/2015  12      20
1003    SWATHY  02/08/2015  10  8   10
1004    DEVAN   02/08/2015  13  9   10
1005    VIKAS   03/08/2015  14  12  10
1006    MADHAV  07/08/2015  12  11  10
1007    KIRAN   07/08/2015  10  15  20
1008    SWATHY  08/08/2015  10  17  15
```

The user can select a start date and end date option... I need to show the result in a data table like:

If the start date is `02/08/2015` and end date is `05/08/2015`
I have to shows the data table COLUMN heading of data table like below

```
MF01/08/15 ,SOB01/08/15,PCB01/08/15, MF02/08/15 ,SOB02/08/15,PCB02/08/15, MF03/08/15 ,SOB03/08/15,PCB03/08/15,.............MF05/08/15,SOB05/08/15,PCB05/08/15,TOTALMF,TOTALSOB,
TOTALPCB

NAME    MF01/08/15 SOB01/08/15  PCB01/08/2015   MF02/08/15 SOB02/08/15 Total
MF  Total
SOb Total
PCB
KIRAN               10  20  10  12      20          22  20  30
SWATHY              10  8   10                              
DEVAN               13                                      
VIKAS                           14  12  10          14  12  10
MADHAV
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stored procedure to tranform tha data and call that and the headings would all be OK.
At a glance, I think you'd want to utilise a PIVOT table in the stored procedure.

Good luck

Comment: if I use PIVOT table, it only get the date from that query result only, but I need to show the heading is our start date to end date.

Comment: Alias the columns in the result set to be what you want them to be.